# Get all users in an ADgroup with the displayname

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I am trying to get the members of a list of groups from a csv. The script i created below outs puts the group names. My question is : I want to get DisplayName instead of  users name.

```
get-content "C:\temp\glist.csv" | foreach {get-adgroup -identity "$_" -properties * | select Name,Description, @{n='Members';e={$_.members -replace '^cn=([^,]+).+$','$1' -join '; '}} | export-csv "C:\temp\group_info $currentdate.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I entirely understood which property you can to get out, but try this instead, it will get the `Name` property instead for each group member:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\glist.csv" `
    | ForEach {
        Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * | select Name, Description, @{n='Members';e={($_.Members | Get-ADObject -Properties Name) -replace '^cn=([^,]+).+$','$1' -join '; '}} `
      } `
    | export-csv "C:\temp\group_info $currentdate.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```